# I am looking to use R programming to statistical correlation with 3 fields

Tags: r, statistics

I wish to investigate if staff well being scores (this is represented as %) for different companies has a correlation between the company staff headcount (this is numeric) and how the regulator view of the company (requires improvement, good and outstanding). Can someone tell me what statistical analysis would be useful and code R code, please?
Thank you

[Here is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH80c.png):

```
  Company health and wellbeing score Head Count    Regulator ranking
1       A                        89%       5000                 good
2       b                        70%       3000 requires improvement
3       c                        55%        400          outstanding
4       d                        44%       2000          outstanding
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have a look at the [correlation function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/cor) from R. However, correlation is only defined for numeric values. As your question is not directly related to a coding problem, please have a look at [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for general questions regarding correlation.

Comment: Assuming each row is a different company (which is the case in the sample data shown)  `fm <- lm(wb ~ hc * reg, mydata); anova(fm)` and check the significance (the Pr column and note stars that are shown if significant)  of the interaction term.

Comment: Hi user410084, welcome to Stack Overflow. This website focuses on *specific* **programing** questions. It seems your question centers more on selection and interpretation of statistical analysis. If the guidance you have received from the posters above isn't enough to resolve your issues, your question might be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! This does belong in CrossValidated, but I'll give it a shot.

If this is the entirety of your data you cannot conduct statistical analysis on it. There is not enough data. If you had enough data, there are still some issues. Pearson's Correlation does not work with a categorical variables, a probit/logit models needs a binary dependent variable. You can always recode the dependent variable. A linear probability model would give a biased answer and is never recommended for categorical questions. There are multivariate probit models, but those are a bit more sophisticated. Honestly,  I would likely stick with some cross tabs here and try to validated with a probit (after recoding).

Comment: what do you think of this fm <- lm(wb ~ hc * reg, mydata); anova(fm) its only of the rely i received.

Comment: Eh. If n=4 like your data suggests, regression is out of the question. How many observations do you have?

Comment: n=224 what about a poisson distribution